# Disable post of a button within a form_tag in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, post

My code:

```
= form_tag(function(), method: :post) do
  %button.button-one
  %button.button-two
```

Both buttons trigger a post. How can I disable the post-request of the second button **without** moving it out of the form_tag?

Comment: Did you try `method: :get`?

Comment: I want to use a post request.

Comment: What does the button do?

Comment: The first button should post the form, the second button should show a dialog via javascript.

Comment: Then on second button's class add JavScript/jQuery listner and do `event.preventDefault();` and then show your modal code.